# Button opens form 2 then cell double click in Datagridview on form 2 sends variable back to form 1 C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, datagridview

I have a C# .NET Forms application that requires sending variable(s) from one form to another.

Form 1 has a button that when clicked opens Form 2, Form 2 has a datagirdview that I would like to have the user double click a cell and the data from that cell (or multiple cells) can be passed back to Form 1 and Form 2 will close at that point.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: That all sounds very interesting - I'd love to see the code you have so far. If you don't have anything, I'm afraid we can't write it for you - check with Google and come back when you have some proof you've tried to solve this on your own. Good luck!

Comment: See my two form project on the following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @jdweng Thank you so much, put me on exactly the right path... I get a little confused with a situation like this and knew some one could point me in a good direction. Thanks again for the help!